# Can a TLB (Load Word) exception be caused by incorrect compiler options usage?

Tags: c, exception, memory, vxworks, tlb

I am getting a TLB (Load Word or Instruction Fetch) exception in VxWorks. When I analyze further I understood that the memory address which is being referred doesn't point to a valid memory location.

As far as I understand, this problem could be happening because of some memory corruption (possible memory overwrite). But, analysis of code and execution of the same piece of code in Windows under purify doesn't show any memory errors.

So, I am wondering if any compiler options could be causing this? Is it possible?

Also, any pointers for how to debug such issues?

Comment: An alignment issue perhaps? *For instance, in windows 4-byte alignment may be ok, but 8-byte alignment required in vxWorks.* Double check any casts in your code.

Comment: Doubtful.  Not being able to find the statement that corrupts the memory does not mean it isn't there.  You can't get comparable results on a different operating system with a different heap manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, certain processor architectures and throw TLB exception when code compiled with certain compiler flags access memory with certain attributes.  e.g. PowerPC on uncached memory with compiler flags that lead to aligned access to unaligned data.

Yes, but without additional information "Yes" is not helpful for you.